# What does 我要放弃你不再爱我的人 mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I think `我要放弃你不再爱我的人` mean `I want to give up on you someone that is not loving me`.

Based on the (guessing) translation above, the sentence can be grouped as following.

[我要放弃你] [不再爱我][的人]

On the other hand, `我要放弃你不再爱我的人` can mean `I want to give up, you are not loving my body (e.g. you only love my money)` if I group words this way.

[我要放弃] [你][不再爱][我的人]

What does 我要放弃你不再爱我的人 mean? How do you determine what word belongs to what?

Comment: "我要放弃你[这个]不再爱我的人" (I have to give up you, [the person who] doesn't love me anymore ) would be valid, but not "我要放弃你不再爱我的人"

Comment: It sounds like a line in lyrics, not in a normal speech.  I take it as 我要放弃你, 不再爱我的人. 你 is in apposition to 不再爱我的人.

Comment: @dan It's looks like from [lyrics](https://mojim.com/twy181258x1x14.htm) right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

umm...usually we mean the former. The latter can make sense in grammar sometimes, but actually we don't express like that in real life. In the second circumstance you mentioned, we would say 我要放弃，[你爱的][不是][我的人]。(I want to give up, what you love is not my self)

Answer (score 2):

It is an invalid sentence, it probably would be [我要放弃]不再爱我的[人](I wanna give up people that don't love me).

你不再爱**我的**人 literally means 'You don't love **my** person anymore' from grammar view, and nearly no one would use it.